# OpenLDAP will not start - Starting OpenLDAP: slapdrm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ldap/alock'

Tags: debian, openldap, slapd

Hope someone can help me out here. I forgot the OpenLDAP admin password on a debian server and in the process, I specified the password in the slapd config file as follows:

```
olcRootPW: {SHA}W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```

I am following the guide here: http://techiezone.rottigni.net/2011/12/change-root-dn-password-on-openldap/

When I run `service slapd start` I receive the following error:

```
Starting OpenLDAP: slapdrm: cannot remove `/var/lib/ldap/alock': No such file or directory
 failed!
```

I removed this but to no avail.

I have restarted the server however this did not make any difference. I have full access to the server.

Any suggestions on how to get OpenLDAP running again?

Comment: Look in the init script - this looks like an error there (an "rm" command), not from slapd itself.  Try ``sh -x /etc/init.d/slapd start`` (assuming you're still running a sysv'ish init with startup shell scripts - if you're on systemd, thereis some similar method but i don't know how you'd go about it.

Comment: Hi Dan. When I run this, here is the response: http://pastebin.com/XYAMtaCh

Comment: are you sure the /var/lib/ldap directory exists?  is your database there?

Comment: which version of Debian and OpenLDAP are you using (`apt-cache show slapd | egrep "^Version:"`)

Answer (score 1):

somewhere in the `slapd_start` function of your `/etc/init.d/slapd` script, there is a line similar to:

```
 rm /var/lib/ldap/alock
```

now, for whatever reasons, this file is non-existant, and the script stops because it fails to remove the non-existant file (which is obviously hard to remove, as it is not there anymore).

you can simply fix this by telling `rm` to try harder using the `-f` (aka `--force` flag). so change the above line in the script to

```
 rm -f /var/lib/ldap/alock
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, I was not aware using the -f flag will also make end rm with success status even there was no file to delete.

Comment: @alphamikevictor, the manpage says *-f: ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt*; so it's really a "force success" rather than "force remove"